# Preview of widget not showing correct image after update

Tags: android

I have an app that has an widget preview image. I recently updated this image on the app, but in a device with Lollipop (5.0) version of android, the preview image of the widget shows the old image (the one I replaced). The same doesn't occur in devices without Lollipop.

I turned the resources folder upside down searching for the old image, but it is correctly updated in all the places (actually, it is only in one folder, as I have only one image of the preview).

Just to give more info, I'm using Android Studio 1.0-rc1, and this problem only occurs in my Nexus 4 with lollipop (5.0) running on it.
I tested in some emulators with Lollipop, and the same happened.

It's important to highlight that if I never installed any previous version of the app (with the old widget preview image), when I install the new version the preview image appears to be correct.

Is anyone having the same problem, or knows how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, also ensured that the old previewImage is gone everywhere and did clean build and all that but still the the old previewImage I had still shows up.

Comment: Hi @TobiasLindberg, I'm relieved to see that I'm not crazy :) I filled an issue at the android issue tracker. Give star it if you want to know when people at google will solve (or not) it. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81076&thanks=81076&ts=1417102714

Comment: Yep same issue here as well

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue! Having the same problem in Lolli 5.0 on Moto X and Nexus 5 with 5.0.1.

Comment: my workaround was just restarting the device.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I managed to work around it (on Nexus 5) by going to the settings of the launcher app (Settings -> Apps -> Google App) and deleting the cache.

Comment: Yeah had the same problem, pretty much did the above except specifically went to Settings->Apps->Google App->Manage Space->Clear Launcher Data.. Which meant I had to setup my homescreen again. But at least my preview showed

Comment: @FlashAsh99's comment worked for me, spookypeanut's answer didn't work for me

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked for me on a Nexus 4 / Android 5.1

Answer (score 6):

I also had this same issue and the answer by @spookypeanut put me on the right track.

My phone is running CyanogenMod so I had to go to app Launcher3 (com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet), clear cache and force stop it. After it reloaded all the previews updated.

Comment: Cool. I noticed that this is the path to solve hits problem. But I haven't found a way to solve it for the end user :(

Comment: thansk, clear cache only is not enough, force stop worked for me

Comment: Restarting Nova Launcher clears the widget preview cache for me. (Settings > Advanced > Restart Nova Launcher)